# Putting an underscore between words in Python

Tags: python-3.x

The input for this problem is 
yellow
daisy
6

I am asked to make the output say this:

`First password: yellow_Daisy`

The only way I know how to add the underscore is to input this...

```
password1 = favoriteColor
password11 = pets_name 
print("First password:", '', password1, "_", password11, sep='')
```

I used the `sep=''` to take the spaces out of the password but by doing this took the space away after the "password:"
the space needs to be there because zybooks is strict.

Can you please help me?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

**input**

```
yellow daisy 6
```

**code**

```
inp = input("something")
inp = inp.split()
print("First password: "+inp[0]+"_"+inp[1].capitalize())
```

**output**

```
First password: yellow_Daisy
```

Comment: I am confused on this. (sorry, im new)...what is the something? and zybooks isn't recognizing inp or split

Comment: What’s the use of 6?

Comment: well he didn't say he needed it so i just omited it, i only think he knows what the 6 is for

Comment: @MattSanders22 something is the line i writes in the prompt when asking yout for an input, inp is just a name you can make what you want, '.split()' , splits the string at spaces and turns it in to a list.

Comment: @jonaswolff, thought it sill limit. What if the input is only one word, let say yellow, and if there are more than 2 words?

Comment: how do you want to acheive your output if your are not given both the color and the name?, and more than 2 is fine this just takes the first word and the second word and uses, maybe you can specify exactly how you want the code to act

Comment: I'm getting an EOF error when putting "inp = input("something")

Comment: thats because you just added a " in the beginning, you never ended it

Comment: I just added that on here to specify what I was typing in the prompt. thats not in my code

Comment: what version of python are you using, i just tested my code in python 3.6.1, and runs fine

Comment: Its zybooks, for school. Idk what version it uses

Comment: maybe they are using python 2.x, how ever you specified 3.x as the tag, in the case of python 2.x write 'raw_innput()' instead of 'input()'

Comment: i don't think i can help you beond this though, i only know how the standart python works.